# MySQL connection error while transferring data using mysql.connector using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I currently work with data transfer between databases using python.
I use mysql.connector for the connection establishment of the MySQL databases.
the tables in the dbs have a data around 1 million or so. When I try to fetch the whole data (i need the whole data) in a table  of a particular database and insert those data into another table in another database, I frequently get connection error ( 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ).But if the data is around 100k or so, it gets executed without any error.Otherwise, the connection is lost midway. Both the databases are in separate remote servers.
Is there any way to solve this error?

```
  query_from = "select * from db_name.table_name"
    cursor.execute(query_from)
    query_to = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {}".format(tablename, column names, values)
    cursor.execute(query_to)
```

Edit: I cannot Change max_allowed_packet=64M in file /etc/mysql/my.cnf since the servers since I don't have privileges. also, executing the command

```
connection.execute('set max_allowed_packet=67108864')
```

shows that I don't have privilege to do so.

Comment: You have to do it in 100k chunks then.

Comment: is it using any time delay?. can  u please explain

Comment: Actually, which part of the query returning `lost connection`? The `SELECT` or `INSERT`?

Comment: the select query is executed successfully. connection loses when insert starts

Comment: I'm sorry because I myself have not extensively done such operation. See if you can get any idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099389/mysql-insert-into-select-query-is-too-slow-to-copy-100-million-rows

Comment: Thank you for your help @FaNo_FN , i'll refer it